# Get specific number of paginated results using ExecuteSegmented

Tags: c#, azure, pagination, azure-table-storage

My understanding of Azure table storage is that we should use `ExecuteSegmented` for granular control of paged queries. That's fine, but if I want to get (eg) 500 results the closest I can get is something like this:

```
TableQuery<Footwear> query = 
table.CreateQuery<Footwear>().Where(f => f.PartitionKey == partitionKey).Take(500).AsTableQuery();

TableContinuationToken token = null;
List<Footwear> shoes = new List<Footwear>();

do
{
    TableQuerySegment<Footwear> queryResult = query.ExecuteSegmented(token);
    token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
    shoes.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
} while (token != null && (tableQuery.TakeCount < rows.Count));
```

Which sort of works, in that (eg) the first paged query returns 300 results, so it uses the token to get another page, but then the second page returns (eg) 250 results.. The consequence being that I ideally wanted 500 results, but I got 550

Is there a better way of tackling this so that I get exactly 500 results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is keep on decreasing the records count to fetch in each query iteration. So you start with 500 records to fetch and you get back 300 records. In the next iteration, you try to get back only 200 records. If you get 200 records back, you simply break out of the loop otherwise keep on iterating.

Something like:

```
        var totalResultsToFetch = 500;
        TableQuery<Footwear> query = table.CreateQuery<Footwear>().Where(f => f.PartitionKey == partitionKey).Take(totalResultsToFetch).AsTableQuery();
        TableContinuationToken token = null;
        List<Footwear> shoes = new List<Footwear>();
        do
        {
            TableQuerySegment<Footwear> queryResult = query.ExecuteSegmented(token);
            token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
            shoes.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
            totalResultsToFetch -= queryResult.Results.Count;
            query = table.CreateQuery<Footwear>().Where(f => f.PartitionKey == partitionKey).Take(totalResultsToFetch).AsTableQuery();
        } while (token != null && (totalResultsToFetch > 0));
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I'm attempting this, but afraid I have oversimplified my example! (I have the execution of the query in a method, meaning I can't easily create a new query). I'm instead trying to edit query.TakeCount within the loop, but this isn't working... Some refactoring required I fear

Comment: To be honest, I didn't run the code myself. Let me try to run this code actually.

Comment: I just ran the code above and it seems to run fine. Can you share some more details as to why you can't create a new query?

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. I'm sure this technique will work fine once I refactor my code. At the moment I pass the tableQuery to a method. I had hoped I could just alter the tableQuery.TakeCount, but it seems that when I loop around and call ExecuteSegmented again it resets the TakeCount back to it's original value.  Don't worry for now, if I get stuck further I'll probably throw a new question up!